# Jquery wont load ActionResult from controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I've got main layout and here i've got a simple jquery code to load action from controller:

```
var url = "Logowanie/ikonaWiadomosci";

$.get(url, null, function (data) {
$("#kontrolkaWiadomosci").html(data);
            });
```

The problem is, this code works only when user is on main page, for example "www.mypage.com". But when users is on page for example "www.mypage.com/home/user", than code wont work. i think the problem is with "url", but I dont know what to do with that.. This is very important for me. Do You have any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("ikonaWiadomosci","Logowanie")';

$.get(url, null, function (data) {
    $("#kontrolkaWiadomosci").html(data);
});
```

Comment: I resolved this problem using var url ="../Logowanie/ikonaWiadomosci", but Your version looks much better. Thank You for answering, works fine ! :)